# How to add street view to google map (ruby on rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-street-view

I'm using "**gmaps4rails**" on rails,

it is useful, I can show the direction form A to B, and some markers on google maps.

Now, I need some advanced features:

1. I want to show "**Street View**" on google maps,like this   http://www.trulia.com/property/3064331264-482-Mariposa-Ave-Mountain-View-CA-94041
2. I noticed that in the left of this map http://www.trulia.com/property/3064331264-482-Mariposa-Ave-Mountain-View-CA-94041, you can click "Comparables","Estimates","Schools"...

how are these features achieved in rails?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The answer doesn't really have much to do with rails.

Take a look at this [sample code from Google](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple).

In particular, take a look at the javascript:

```
function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: fenway,
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var panoramaOptions = {
      position: fenway,
      pov: {
        heading: 34,
        pitch: 10,
        zoom: 1
      }
    };
    var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"),panoramaOptions);
    map.setStreetView(panorama);
  }
```